# non-numeric argument to 'pairs' en R

Tags: r

Intentaba hacer una matrix de correlaciones con el comando `scatterplotMatrix()` en R y obtengo este error:

> scatterplotMatrix(a_heterophylla_NAY_SIN, spread=FALSE, lty.smooth=2,
>   main="Matriz correlaciones") Error in pairs.default(x, labels =
>   var.labels, cex.axis = cex.axis, cex.main = cex.main,  :
>   non-numeric argument to 'pairs'

Que significa y como lo resuelvo ?? 
Ayuda por favor !!

Comment: Bienvenida, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask] así también como hacer un [mcve]. En cuanto a tu pregunta: el error podría deberse a varias causas, para intentar saberlo, debería adjuntar el código que está generando el error. Te sugiero que edites la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a tratar de responder tu pregunta en función de la información que diste. Fundamentalmente el problema es de datos, particularmente en `a_heterophylla_NAY_SIN`, el error se dispara cuando `scatterplotMatrix()` invoca internamente a [`pairs()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/pairs.html) asignándo el parámetro `x` con tu objeto `a_heterophylla_NAY_SIN` , si ves la documentación:

> x: the coordinates of points given as numeric columns of a matrix or
>   data frame. Logical and factor columns are converted to numeric in the
>   same way that data.matrix does.

Es decir, se espera una matriz o un dataframe y fundamentalmente todos los valores deben ser "mapeados" a valores numéricos. Revisando el código de  [`pairs()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/pairs.html), vemos:

```
if (!is.matrix(x)) {
        x <- as.data.frame(x)
        for(i in seq_along(names(x))) {
            if(is.factor(x[[i]]) || is.logical(x[[i]]))
               x[[i]] <- as.numeric(x[[i]])
            if(!is.numeric(unclass(x[[i]])))
                stop("non-numeric argument to 'pairs'")
        }
    } else if (!is.numeric(x)) stop("non-numeric argument to 'pairs'")
```

O sea, o `a_heterophylla_NAY_SIN` es una matriz NO numérica o un objeto que aun mapeado como un dataframe, alguna de sus columnas no es numérica. La solución entonces pasaría por "normalizar" `a_heterophylla_NAY_SIN`, y eventualmente convertir cualquier valor no numérico en un Factor, de manera que pueda ser procesado correctamente.

Comment: Entiendo, ¿y como hago para "normalizar" esas variables que no son numéricas?

Comment: @GabiQuesadaA: Si las conviertes a un `Factor` pueden tratarse como numéricas. Por ejemplo `df$columna1 <- as.factor(df$columna1)`.